# Copy value of calculated field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, copy, calculated-field

In MySQL or MariaDB, is it possible to copy the results in calculated fields and not copy the actual formulae? Like in excel I can paste values and not the actual equations associated with those cells. I want to do that in MySQL.

Comment: Like `show create table` for virtual/generated columns (there's also probably an `information_schema` expose of this)? Or do you mean something different.

Comment: Or are you saying `select sleep(1)` has a column name of `sleep(1)` being the formulae, but you can rename columns in select like `select sleep(1) as snooze`.

Comment: Well I just created a column and had the values in the column calculate based on values in another column so I don't know what you're talking about.